# Prime Video not streaming

Tags: pi-4

I have installed Rasberry OS and ran the script to get streaming installed.  Netflix and Disney+ is working fine but Prime Video is opening but does not want to stream the video.

The following message pop's up:  A later version of Google Chrome is required for Prime Video. To update, click the Chrome menu (three horizontal stripes) on the browser toolbar, click About Google Chrome, and then click Relaunch.

However chrome says that I am using the most up to date version.  Rasberry OS uses Chromiam.  Can someone please point me in the right direction as I am an extreemly green newby.

Thanks

Comment: Did you research your question first on this site? This looks like an issue that was already solved.

Comment: @Friendlygabe777, there's certainly other questions here about Prime and Netflix freezing in Chromium on a RPi, but I'm not aware of one about Prime complaining of the wrong browser version. If I can't find it, then maybe the OP can't either. Perhaps you could link to it to assist us?

Comment: Ok then. Are you saying you installed chrome on the Raspberry pi? Did you try using chromium instead? Would you please show the script you used? Please edit your question to include the script, and comment if you are using Chrome or Chromium.